# Is the prepared statement cache cleared per request in Rails 3.1?

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, prepared-statement

I've been looking for a while and can't see any mention of when the prepared statement cache is cleared in Rails. Is it cleared after each request like the query cache is?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this too, and it seems that since the prepared statement cache is implemented in the database connectors, the database connector is where it should be cleared.

Looking at activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter, there's 'statement_limit' configuration added in version 1.4.1, that defaults to 250. Any time the adapter adds a statement to the prepared statement cache, it first removes prepared statements from the end of the cache (just an array) until it's under that limit.

If you want to clear all the prepared statements, you can do that by calling `connection.clear_cache!`

This is just for the oracle_enhanced driver. If you're using postgresql or something else, check the docs for that driver instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. I honestly can't remember why I was asking this question but it had something to do with multi-tennancy on Rails. I think they've patched things up so that the query cache isn't an issue any more. :)

Answer (score -1):

From the [middleware documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware):

> ActiveRecord::QueryCache caches all SELECT queries generated in a request. If any INSERT or UPDATE takes place then the cache is cleaned.

Comment: I downvoted because `ActiveRecord::QueryCache` is not where prepared statements are cached. A prepared statement is one that is specifically compiled for that query so that Rails doesn't need to go through the expensive task of recompiling it every request. QueryCache is for storing results of queries.